# How to create confusion matrix on this dtype "tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.SkipDataset"

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, dataset, confusion-matrix, image-classification

I'm working on image dataset having 7 different classes and splitted data based on train, valid, and test .. but when I'm predicting the given code:

```
# predicting labels of testing set and getting their confidences
lbls_true = []
lbls_pred = [] # predicted integer labels
pred_confs = [] # confidences

for i in range(test_size):
    for imgs, lbls in test_set.take(i + 1):
        lbls_true.extend(lbls.numpy().tolist())

        pred_imgs = model.predict(imgs)
        for pred_img in pred_imgs:
            lbls_pred.append(np.argmax(pred_img))
            pred_confs.append(np.max(pred_img))
        break
```

I'm facing memory issue in kaggle.

Help please. I'm new in deep learning.

Comment: dataset type is: tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.SkipDataset